# Node.js cant see any data from Serial port Connected to MSP430 Launch Pad

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, msp430

I am trying to get an Intel Galileo to run Node.js and serialPort.js to collect data being sent from an MSP430 Launch pad (Arduino based board). When I run the code on the Galileo the "Port Open" message is printed so I know the 'open' state has been reached in serialPort but it just wont ever use the data function.

Here is the server code without the functions:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(4000));
var com = require("serialport");

app.get('/', function(request, response){response.sendfile(__dirname + "/home.html");});
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var activeClients = 0;     

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){clientConnect(socket);});

var serialPort = new com.SerialPort("/dev/ttyS0", {
    baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false,
    parser: com.parsers.readline("\n")
  });

serialPort.on('open',function() {
  console.log('Port open ');
  console.log(process.argv[0] + " " + " " + process.argv[1]);

serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("Data recieved: ");
      console.log(data.toString());
      io.sockets.emit('heartUpdate', {heartcrc:data});
      emitHeartRate(data);
  });
serialPort.on('close', function () {
      console.log('Port close'); 
  });
serialPort.on('error', function () {
      console.log('Error');
  });


});
```

Here is the setup script run on the Galileo before launching the server code to set up the ports on the Galileo:

```
#!/bin/bash 

# Initialize sysfs to use the uart on pins 0 and 1 as /dev/ttyS0:
echo -n "4" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo -n "40" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo -n "41" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo -n "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction
echo -n "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio40/direction
echo -n "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio41/direction
echo -n "strong" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio40/drive
echo -n "strong" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio41/drive
echo -n "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value
echo -n "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio40/value
echo -n "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio41/value
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 raw
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

Here is the code on the MSP430 which sets up and transmits data:

```
//UART configuration settings
UCA0CTL1 &= UCSWRST;                            //Reset UART control register
UCA0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCMSB;                    //UART timer input MCLK, enable MSB sent first
                                                //Defaults: Parity disabled, 8 bit data, one stop bit, UART mode, asyncronous
UCA0BR0 = 0x68;                                 //1MHz 9600 baud
UCA0BR1 = 0x00;                                 //1MHz 9600 baud
UCA0MCTL = UCBRS0;                              //Modulation UCBRSx = 1
UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                           //Enable the USCI peripheral (take it out of reset)
```

Here is the pair of functions which are used to transmit the data:

```
void uartCHAR(int txChar)
{

    while (!(IFG2 & UCA0TXIFG));        //Wait for the transmit buffer to be ready
    UCA0TXBUF = (char)txChar;           //Put integer value in to UART transmit buffer in character format

}

void uartTransmit(int tx)
{
    P1OUT |= REDLED;                    //Turn on Red LED
    unsigned int byteSelect = 0xFF00;   //Declare value used to isolate each byte
    unsigned int byteHold = 0;          //Declare varible to hold isolated byte
    unsigned char sendByte = 0;         //Declare a variable to hold the byte to be transmitted
    int k;                              //Declare a variable to be used in the for loop
    for (k = 1; k>=0 ; k--)             //Cycle through the code twice
    {

        byteHold = byteSelect&tx;       //Isoltate each section of 8 bits in the and store in byteHold
        byteHold >>= (8*(k));           //Shift the data down to the lowest byte position
        sendByte = byteHold;
        uartCHAR(sendByte);             //Pass sendByte in to the uartCHAR function
        byteHold = 0;
        byteSelect>>=8;                 //Shift the byte selector to the next section of 8 bits
    }
    P1OUT &= ~REDLED;                   //Turn off Red LED
    uartCHAR('\n');                     //Send symbol to indicate to the parser that the end of the message has arrived
}
```

If someone could point out if I am doing anything wrong I would really appreciate it. I am not getting any output to the screen when it is running. I know that if I had mismatch baud rates then I would get a strange output but there is no output whatsoever so I cant examine and fix it.

Comment: Do you see anything on the TXD line with an oscilloscope or logic analyzer?

Comment: @CL Yes the bit stream that comes out corresponds to the bytes I am sending. I did a test where I sent a known number and it came out in binary. I have a feeling the problem is either that I am not sending the bits in the correct format from the MSP or that the serialPort code is not configured properly to pick it up.

Comment: @CL Is it possible that simply placing the bytes in the transmit buffer does not mean that the start and stop bits are sent ?

Comment: Are you setting up your DCO to use the calibrated 1MHz settings?

Comment: @Headcode is it not set to 1MHz by default ?

Answer (score 0):

The DCO at startup is probably running somewhere close to 1 MHz but you should really use the calibrated settings. I'm not sure what chip you're using but you can include something like the following in your init:

```
DCOCTL = 0x00;
BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;
DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;
```

Since timing for serial communication is very important this could be causing you a problem.